# Reverse query (descending)

Tags: c#, asp.net

How I can get the data from the database descending

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct([QueryString("productID")] int? productId)
{
    var _db = new WingtipToys.Models.ProductContext();
        IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;
        if (productId.HasValue && productId > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.ProductID == productId);
        }
        else
        {
            query = null;
        }
        return query;
}
```

its give me like {1,2,3,.....}
i want it like {n,n-1,....,2,1}
i tried to change in query statement and i am still beginner and i have no idea what the function could do that ! 
can you plz help me !

Comment: And `Product.ProductID` isn't a primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
query = query
    .Where(p => p.ProductID == productId)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.IntColumnYouWantToUse);
```

Comment: Hey Tim, we can do _db.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.productId) itself, right?

Comment: @Mukund You could do that, but as the `Where` clause is already limiting it to items with a single productID.

Comment: @Mukund: yes, but i assume that OP is trying something different. Otherwise he wouldn't get multiple items even if he filters by a single `ProductID`. So the colum he wants to order by is a different column.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534855(v=vs.100).aspx). Then you just give it a key selector

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use: `OrderByDescending`.
However if you just want to flip your list without ordering you can also Reverse the list with `.Reverse()`. But `OrderByDescending` will be the best option.
[Reverse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This will reorder the items in memory in O(n) time, so it is very slow compared to using OrderByDescending, which will execute on the SQL server and return the items in the desired order.